# How to create a custom dropdown to change the content

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, dropdown

I have a custom dropdown and

```
<div class="title__area">
                    <div class="custom-select payment__method">
                      <select>
                        <option value="0">ÖDEME TİPİ</option>
                        <option value="1" class="transfer-selected">Havale - EFT</option>
                        <option value="2" class="credit-card-selected">Kredi Kartı</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row" id="credit-card-selected">
                   
                  </div>
                  <div class="row" id="transfer-selected">
                    </div>
```

And what I am trying to achieve, so if the user selects value 1 which is transfer-selected in this case, I want to show this:

```
<div class="row" id="transfer-selected">
                    </div>
```

And if the user selects value 2 which is credit-card-selected in this case, I want to show this:

```
<div class="row" id="credit-card-selected">

                  </div>
```

My javascript is like this but it doesn't work like I expected:

```
$(".credit-card-selected").click(function () {
  $(".credit-card-selected").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
});

$(".transfer-selected").click(function () {
  $(".transfer-selected").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

And here is my css:

```
.new__order__choice .credit-card-selected {
  display: none;
}

.new__order__choice .credit-card-selected.selected {
  display: block;
}

.new__order__choice .transfer-selected {
  display: none;
}

.new__order__choice .transfer-selected.selected {
  display: block;
}
```

Do you see the reason,

```js
$(".credit-card-selected").click(function() {
  $(".credit-card-selected").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
});

$(".transfer-selected").click(function() {
  $(".transfer-selected").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

```css
.new__order__choice .credit-card-selected {
  display: none;
}

.new__order__choice .credit-card-selected.selected {
  display: block;
}

.new__order__choice .transfer-selected {
  display: none;
}

.new__order__choice .transfer-selected.selected {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title__area">
  <div class="custom-select payment__method">
    <select>
      <option value="0">ÖDEME TİPİ</option>
      <option value="1" class="transfer-selected">Havale - EFT</option>
      <option value="2" class="credit-card-selected">Kredi Kartı</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="credit-card-selected">
 Credit Card
</div>
<div class="row" id="transfer-selected">
  Transfer
</div>
```

Comment: Please click [edit], then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] of the issue

Comment: In  javascript you are used `Class` selected when in HTML you are used `ID` selector, So please change in one of that and check it..

Comment: Don’t try to use click handlers on option elements. Use a `change` handler on the select element itself, and inside check what value the field currently has.

Comment: It looks like you have your answer, but in the future please be sure to specify what the behavior is, vs what you're expecting, instead of just saying "it doesn't work like I expected".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the "change" event of the select

Here is a version using the value of the select to change the corresponding div

```js
$("#paymentOptions").on("change", function() {
  $(".row")
    .hide()
    .eq(this.value - 1).show()
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title__area">
  <div class="custom-select payment__method">
    <select id="paymentOptions">
      <option value="0">ÖDEME TİPİ</option>
      <option value="1">Havale - EFT</option>
      <option value="2">Kredi Kartı</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row hide" id="transfer-selected">
  Transfer
</div>
<div class="row hide" id="credit-card-selected">
  Credit Card
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried your code and thanks. But the problem is I cannot go into this function: $('#paymentOptions').on('change', function() {
  $(".row")
    .hide()
    .eq(this.value - 1).show()
});

Comment: What does that mean? "I cannot go into this function"

Comment: When I write $("#paymentOption").change(function(){  console.log("lksdfldfk")
  $(".row.options")
    .hide()
    .eq(this.value - 1).show()
}); it doesnt write anything. Because as a snippet it is working perfect but in my code, it doesnt change and actually, it doesnt show anything

Comment: I added an ID to your select! `<select id="paymentOptions">`

Comment: Also I use .on("change") - not that it matters

Answer (score 1):

The way of doing that I will use for this kind of functionality

this method allows you to have N `transfer` or `credit-card` banks

```js
const 
  theSelect = document.querySelector('div.payment__method > select')
, thePMI    = document.querySelector('div#payment-method-information')

theSelect.onchange = e =>
  {
  thePMI.className = theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].dataset.payClass
  }
```

```css
#payment-method-information > div {
  display: none; 
  }
#payment-method-information.transfer    > div#transfer,
#payment-method-information.credit-card > div#credit-card {
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="title__area">
  <div class="custom-select payment__method">
    <select>
      <option value="a"                     > ÖDEME TİPİ   </option>
      <option value="b" data-pay-class="transfer"    > Havale - EFT </option>
      <option value="c" data-pay-class="credit-card" > Kredi Kartı  </option>
      <option value="x" data-pay-class="transfer"    > other transfer  </option>
      
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="payment-method-information" class="">
  <div class="row" id="credit-card"> credit card information... </div>
  <div class="row" id="transfer"> transfer information... </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not recommended at all to use className to select something else. User a data attribute or the value of the select

Comment: @mplungjan that's right, I've updated my answser

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just hooking into the wrong events.  The more common way is to use the `change` event on the `<select>`, get the selected value from `event.target.value`, and act based on that.

Once you have that working, I'd just create a simple map between the option values and the IDs of the elements you want to show/hide, and use that as a lookup to toggle the correct class.

Comment: What I have done is something like this: <div class="custom-select payment__method">
                      <select>
                        <option value="0">ÖDEME TİPİ</option>
                        <option value="1">Havale - EFT</option>
                        <option value="2" class="credit-card-selected">Kredi Kartı</option>
                      </select>
                    </div> and js: const selectElement = document.querySelector('.payment__method');

selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.value);
}); but I cannot get anything.

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. Update the question instead. Also you have jQuery, so use it

Comment: magic bean, the problem with that code is that your `<select>` is what will emit the `change` event, not the parent div.